# Selenium Grid with Protractor: SessionNotCreatedError at Object.checkLegacyResponse

Tags: selenium, grid, protractor

I'm new to Selenium Grid and I'm trying to execute a protractor test on a remote node.

I'm using a Virtual Machine as Hub, the Node is my local machine which is also the client.

Both hub and node are up and running.

I've set the property seleniumAddress correctly in the conf.js file.

So now when I execute my test by running protractor conf.js, I'm getting this error:

```
E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: Unable to create new service: 
ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05- 
08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'host-name', ip: 'ip-address', os.name: 'Windows 7', 
os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at Object.checkLegacyResponse
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. I tried to fix it by running:
webdriver-manager clean
webdriver-manager update
but it didn't help.

Comment: Post the configurations also (you can mask out internal details like passwords)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean with configurations?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by specifying the location of the chromedriver executable using the argument Dwebdriver.chrome.driver. This argument should be set when starting the node.

[chromedriver documentation](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started)